# Creation of a loop loading values from .txt files

Tags: matlab, loops

i have a problem creating a loop which loads each value from ".txt" files and uses it in some calculations. 
All the values are on the **2nd column** and the **first one** is always on the **9th line** of each file.
Each ".txt" file contains a different number of values on its 2nd column (they all have the same text after the final value), so i want a loop that can read those values and stop whenever it finds that text)

Here is an example of these files ( the values that interest me are the ones under the headline of G (33,55,93...............,18) )

```
Latitude:   34°40'30" North, 
Longitude:  3°16'6" East

Results for:    April

Inclination of plane:    32  deg.
Orientation (azimuth) of plane:  0   deg.
Time        G       Gd      Gc      DNI     DNIc        A       Ad      Ac
05:52       33      33      25      0       0       233     64      311
06:07       55      44      47      246     361     356     105     473
06:22       93      59      92      312     459     444     124     590
06:37       136     73      147     366     538     514     138     684
06:52       183     86      207     410     602     572     150     760
07:07       232     98      271     447     656     620     160     823
07:22       283     110     337     478     701     659     168     874
16:37       283     110     337     478     701     659     168     874
16:52       232     98      271     447     656     620     160     823
17:07       183     86      207     410     602     572     150     760
17:22       136     73      147     366     538     514     138     684
17:37       93      59      92      312     459     444     124     590
17:52       55      44      47      246     361     356     105     473
18:07       33      33      25      0       0       233     64      311
18:22       18      18      14      0       0       9       8       7

G: Global irradiance on a fixed plane  (W/m2)
Gd: Diffuse irradiance on a fixed plane  (W/m2)
Gc: Global clear-sky irradiance on a fixed plane  (W/m2)
DNI: Direct normal irradiance   (W/m2)
DNIc: Clear-sky direct normal irradiance  (W/m2)
A: Global irradiance on 2-axis tracking plane  (W/m2)
Ad: Diffuse irradiance on 2-axis tracking plane  (W/m2)
Ac: Global clear-sky irradiance on 2-axis tracking plane  (W/m2)

PVGIS (c) European Communities, 2001-2012
```

Comment: If you always have the same number of lines in the file, you could use `M = dlmread(filename,delimiter,[R1 C1 R2 C2])`. If not, you'll have to write a little routine using `fopen`, `fscanf`, and `fclose`.

Comment: @Tom thank you so much for your quick reply , i don't have the same number of lines , and i used  ` fid = fopen('avril.txt');M = textscan(fid,'%*s%s%*[^\n]'); fclose(fid);A=M{1,1};avril0552= str2num (A{7,1}); ` ( this is for the first value ) to load every value alone , but when i tried to do a loop , it didn't work :/